# Scrollable content inside a fixed element with max-height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a scrollable popup that has a header, body and footer.

It has a fixed positioning parent that has a max-height depending on the screen, and both header and footer are absolute positioned on top and bottom respectively.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the body scrollable on max-height reaching, **using only CSS**. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-header">Header</div>
  <div class="popup-body">Body</div>
  <div class="popup-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
}

.popup-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
}

.popup-body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.popup-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

You can see it in further detail here: https://jsfiddle.net/r7ztu8oL/ (*note: fill the body with `Body <br />` until it overflows*)

Comment: add overflow:auto to .popup and position fixed to panel-header & footer

Answer (score 0):

In order for `.popup-body` to be scrollable you have to set the `height` property to fixed number.

**[Solution 1]: The **CSS** code:

```
.popup-body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px; // Fixed height
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Check out this updated version of [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ztu8oL/1/).

### EDIT:

**[Solution 2]**:

- Remove all `position: absolute` properties and set them to `position: relative`. You can't expect to have a responsive layout, when you throw your elements out of the flow.
- Remove all `width: 100%` properties and substitute them with `display: block` in `.popup-header`, `.popup-body` and `.popup-footer`. It will achieve the same result and it's more efficient in your case.

Check out [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ztu8oL/3/) for a visual representation.

The **CSS** code (with `position: relative`) :

```
.popup-header {
  position: relative;
}

.popup-footer {
  position: relative;
}
```

### EDIT 2:

**[Solution 3]**: 
- In this solution, you must set everything to `position: absolute` and set a `min-height` for your popup window. I have set it to `80%`.

The **CSS** code (showing `min-height` and `position: absolute`):

```
.popup {
    min-height: 80%;
}

.popup-header, .popup-body, .popup-footer {
  position: absolute;
}
```

See a third solution closest to what you want [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ztu8oL/4/).

### EDIT 3:

**[Solution 4]**: (With JavaScript)

• Remove `min-height` from the popup.

** The CSS code** (slightly changed margin and removed min-height of popup):

```
.popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
}

.popup-body {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**:

```
<script>
    // Declare variables
    var body = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-body")[0];
    var maxHeight = body.parentElement.style.maxHeight;
    var bodyHeight = 0;
    const bodyMargin = 100;

    // Get the height of the first 5 children
    for (var i = 0; i < body.children.length; i++) {
        bodyHeight += body.children[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    // Set the height to the popup (parent)
    bodyheight = (bodyHeight <= maxHeight) ? bodyHeight : maxHeight;
    body.parentElement.style.height = bodyMargin + bodyHeight + "px";
</script>
```

Since none of the previous solutions was adequate, it seems like JavaScript is inevitable. The script is very simple and easy to implement.

You can check out the updated jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ztu8oL/5/).

Comment: I dont think giving height in px is solution to this problem

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I want the popup to reduce it's height below 400px when the body is smaller... And if I use a `height:200px` for example, then the popup takes that as the maximum height, and I want it to take all the possible screen.

Comment: Check out the fiddle I have provided. Substitute the`height` with something else and it won't work as wanted by the OP.

Comment: @Mumpo WIth JavaScript that would be very easy.

Comment: Sorry I need it not to use Javascript. About your edit, the absolute positioning of the header and footer have a reasoning, it's because even though I want the body to be scrollable, I want the footer to be static in the bottom. What fills the popup container is the body, hence the 40px margins on top and bottom. In your solution I don't see the footer

Comment: Ok, removing the 40px margins with your solution shows the footer, but again, it won't resize to fit when the body is smaller than 300px.

Comment: Absolute positioning has a reasoning. That's why it exists. It's not to be used when responsive layouts are desired though. It's just flawed logic. You can't expect it to react in a responsive manner when it's thrown out of the content flow. If you want one to be absolutely positioned then all must follow that rule.

Comment: But if I remove the `<br />` tags it is still using the 80% of the screen, I need it to resize to fit. Thank you though, I value your efforts very much.

Comment: @Mumpo Please check out my 3rd edit. It's the last one. I know you said no JavaScript, but the script I wrote for you is very easy, small and it works perfectly as you want. And you can just copy and paste it in you HTML. Without a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late to the party but here is an example of what I think you are looking for. HTML and CSS only. The body is scrollable when the content is larger than the available space and the popup is responsive. The setting a height of 100% - (header + footer) is what allows the body to be the right size so that any overflow can be scrolled. And obviously overflow-y:auto is important. The css is as follows:

```
.popup {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    width:400px;
    max-width:calc(100vw - 20px);
    height:100%;
    max-height:calc(100vh - 20px);
    margin:auto;
    background:white;
}
header, footer {
    background:#666;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
}
.body {
    padding:10px;
    line-height:1.4;
    height:calc(100% - 140px);
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/chadrikz/pen/VzmdWB?editors=1100

Answer (score -2):

```
.popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.popup-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
}
.popup-body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.popup-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality content on Stack Overflow.  Please add some description about why this solves the problem posed in the question.